# wird oder werden?

Tags: grammatical-number, list

Ich habe eine Aufzählung, bei der ich mir unsicher bzgl. der Verwendung von "wird" oder "werden" bin:

> Für die Untersuchung wird eine minimale Menge von 9 kg, eine mittlere Menge von 12 kg und eine maximale Menge von 15 kg festgelegt.

Tendeziell würde ich sagen, dass "wird" verwendet wird, da sich alles auf die "Menge" bezieht.

Passt das?

Comment: Wenn das Aktiv verwendet würde, könnte man dieser Entscheidung aus dem Weg gehen.

Comment: Danke. Das Aktiv kann ich leider in diesem Fall nicht verwenden.

Comment: "Werden" wäre hier korrekt, da es sich um eine Aufzählung handelt. Wenn Du sichergehen willst, dann formulierst Du den Satz um, zu *Für die Untersuchung wird die Verwendung einer minimalen Menge von 9kg, einer mittleren Menge von 12kg und einer maximalen Menge von 15kg festgelegt*. Dann ist nämlich "die Verwendung" das Subjekt und das Verb dadurch im Singular.

Answer (score 2):

Normalerweise steht bei mehreren Subjekten, die mit "und" verknüpft sind, das Verb im Plural.

Bei mehreren Subjekten, die mit "entweder ... oder" verknüpft sind, steht dagegen das Verb im Singular.

Man könnte hier argumentieren, dass es sich um eine logische "entweder ... oder" Reihe handelt, weil die Menge ja nicht *gleichzeitig* 9, 12 und 15kg sein kann.

Ziehe in deinem Beispiel die "Menge" aus der Aufzählung und du wirst sehen, dass du gar nicht anders kannst, als den Singular zu verwenden:

> Für die Untersuchung wird eine minimale von 9 kg, eine mittlere von 12 kg und eine maximale Menge von 15 kg festgelegt.

Comment: Kann es auch sein, dass es davon abhängt, ob die Festlegung der 3 Größen in einem Rutsch geschieht, oder ob es 3 getrennte Festlegungsvorgänge sind?

Comment: Es ist kein entweder ... oder, da die minimale Menge, die mittlere Menge und die maximale Menge natürlich gleichzeitig existieren können. Außerdem klingt Dein Beispiel für mich sehr holprig, ich würde eher *Für die Untersuchung werden eine minimale, eine mittlere und eine maximale Menge von 9 kg, 12 kg bzw. 15 kg festgelegt.* schreiben.

Comment: Es werden alle drei Mengen festgelegt, also plural. Da gibt es keine Entweder-Oder-Reihe. Dabei ist es auch egal in welcher Reihenfolge oder im welchem zeitlichem Abstand dies geschieht.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt eine einfache Regel (zu den Ausnahmen weiter unten):

> Wenn das Subjekt nur ein Ding ist, muss das Verb in Singular stehen.
>   Wenn das Subjekt nicht ein Ding ist, sollte das Verb in Plural stehen.

Das Subjekt ist dann nicht ein Ding, wenn eine der beiden Bedingungen zutrifft:

1. Das Subjekt steht im Plural
2. Das Subjekt ist eine Aufzählung

Beispiel für 1:

> **Die Brüder** schlafen. (Falsch wäre: *... schläft*)

Beispiel für 2:

> **Georg, Erwin und Friedrich** schlafen. (Falsch wäre: *... schläft*)

Das gilt auch, wenn das Subjekt nicht an Position 1 steht:

> Im Haus am Strand schlafen **Georg, Erwin und Friedrich.**

Und auch, wenn ein Hilfsverb existiert, so dass das Prädikat aus mehreren Verben besteht, die an verschiedenen Stellen des Satzes stehen:

> richtig: Im Haus am Strand **werden** Georg, Erwin und Friedrich **schlafen.**
>   falsch: Im Haus am Strand **wird** Georg, Erwin und Friedrich **schlafen.**

Oder auch:

> richtig: Im Haus am Strand **werden** der kleine Bruder, der mittlere Bruder und der große Bruder **schlafen.**
>   falsch: Im Haus am Strand **wird** der kleine Bruder, der mittlere Bruder und der große Bruder **schlafen.**

Auch dann, wenn die Bestandteile der Aufzählung selbst längere Nominalgruppen sind:

> Im Haus am Strand **werden** der kleine fröhliche Bruder mit den roten Haaren, der mittlere faule Bruder mit der großen Nase und der große traurige Bruder mit den langen Bart schlafen.

Im Beispielsatz ist diese Aufzählung das Subjekt:

> eine minimale Menge von 9 kg, eine mittlere Menge von 12 kg und eine maximale Menge von 15 kg

Das ist eindeutig eine Aufzählung, also nicht nur ein Ding. Also:

> richtig: Für die Untersuchung **werden** eine minimale Menge von 9 kg, eine mittlere Menge von 12 kg und eine maximale Menge von 15 kg festgelegt.
>   falsch: Für die Untersuchung **wird** eine minimale Menge von 9 kg, eine mittlere Menge von 12 kg und eine maximale Menge von 15 kg festgelegt.

---

### Aber

> Marmor, Stein und Eisen **brechen.**

Das wäre nach obiger Regel richtig. Und weil Drafi Deutscher im Jahr 1965 den Schlager

> Marmor, Stein und Eisen **bricht**

veröffentlich hat, der einen Grammatikfehler im Titel enthielt, wurde dieses Lied auch von einigen Radiosendern nicht gespielt. Aber der Schlager wurde trotzdem ein großer Erfolg, und die Grammatikregel war damit aufgeweicht. Die Ausnahme galt zuerst nur für Materialien und heißt auch *»singularis materialis«*, sie dehnt sich seit einigen Jahren aber auch auf alle Aufzählungen aus.

Bezieht man einen konservativen Standpunkt, muss man in Satz aus der Frage also unbedingt den Plural verwenden. Wer progressiver mit der Sprache umgehen will, kann wählen.

Comment: Existiert der Begriff »singularis materialis« tatsächlich, bzw. ist er ein anerkannter Begriff oder Erfindung des Liedertexters? Ob der Schlager das allein salonfähig machte halte ich für fraglich. In der Dichtung und in Redewendungen gibt es dafür ja schon vorher Beispiele.

Comment: @mtwde: Nicht der Liedertexter Drafi Deutscher hat den Begriff *»singularis materialis«* erfunden, sondern sein Freund und Kollege Christian Bruhn (der z.B. *»Ein bisschen Spaß muss sein«* für Roberto Blanko geschrieben hat), und er bezog sich damit auf schon davor existierende Wendungen wie z.B. *»Glück und Glas, wie leicht <del>brechen die</del> bricht das«* oder *»Da <del>sind</del> ist Hopfen und Malz verloren«.* Germanisten nahmen den Begriff auf und heute ist das ein etablierter Fachterminus.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, daß *singularis materialis* ein etablierter Fachterminus ist. Jedenfalls konnte ich beim Googeln keine einzige Fachpublikation finden, in der der Begriff verwendet wird.

Comment: Deswegen sprach ich von Texter und nicht Interpret (auch wenn Bruhn wohl der Komponist war), was aber für die Nachfrage unerheblich ist :) . Eine Recherche des Begriffs verweist entweder auf den Schlager oder einen mittlerweile gelöschten Wikipedia-Artikel. In dessen [Löschdiskussion](https://bit.ly/2C5RecL) oder auch [hier](https://www.noz.de/deutschland-welt/vermischtes/artikel/642722/vor-50-jahren-drafi-deutscher-sturmt-mit-dem-marmor-song-die-charts) wird der Ausdruck als Scherz bezeichnet. Daher die Frage, ob der Begriff wirklich anerkannt ist oder ein "Insider-Scherz".

Comment: "[...] der einen Grammatikfehler im Titel enthielt, wurde dieses Lied auch von einigen Radiosendern nicht gespielt. " Hast du einen Beleg dafür?

Comment: @infinitezero: Du darfst gerne selber googeln und dir dann eine der vielen Fundstellen aussuchen. Probier es mit diesem Suchtext: *marmor stein und eisen bricht nicht im bayerischen rundfunk*

Comment: Das funktioniert so nicht. Wer eine Behauptung aufstellt hat auch für den Beleg zu sorgen. Danke aber für den Google query.

Comment: @mtwde: Im Fall von *»Marmor Stein und Eisen bricht«* war Drafi Deutscher meines Wissens Textdichter, Komponist und Interpret. Er hat aber während des Schaffensprozesses mit Christian Bruhn über das Werk gesprochen.